# Android Pushwoosh IllegalStateException: Application does not define permission com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE

Tags: android, android-notifications, pushwoosh

I have a problem today. When I try to register to receive a push from Pushwoosh

```
Pushwoosh.getInstance().registerForPushNotifications()
```

It throws an exception like that

```
E/Pushwoosh: Exception occurred
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Application does not define permission com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE
    at com.pushwoosh.firebase.internal.registrar.a$b.a(Unknown Source:17)
    at com.pushwoosh.firebase.internal.registrar.a$b.a(Unknown Source:30)
    at com.pushwoosh.firebase.internal.registrar.a.checkDevice(Unknown Source:2)
    at com.pushwoosh.notification.PushwooshNotificationManager.a(Unknown Source:45)
    at com.pushwoosh.Pushwoosh.a(Unknown Source:23)
    at com.pushwoosh.Pushwoosh.lambda$HgkxfkcfE_k-Lm_xVXJ-mTVOJ3g(Unknown Source:0)
    at com.pushwoosh.-$$Lambda$Pushwoosh$HgkxfkcfE_k-Lm_xVXJ-mTVOJ3g.a(Unknown Source:6)
    at com.pushwoosh.inapp.f.a.a(Unknown Source:11)
    at com.pushwoosh.inapp.f.a.lambda$qCb0Pyb8Qrzu-2CtVmkrEeLg1C0(Unknown Source:0)
    at com.pushwoosh.inapp.f.-$$Lambda$a$qCb0Pyb8Qrzu-2CtVmkrEeLg1C0.run(Unknown Source:6)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:900)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:219)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
```

This is my Manifest

```
<manifest ..>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<application ..> </application></manifest>
```

I have tried adding this line to my manifest but still not working

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
```

My device is a Huawei nova 7i, I have tried to settings in my battery follow this [link](https://help.pushwoosh.com/hc/en-us/articles/360028478751-Android-device-cannot-receive-push-notifications-when-an-application-is-force-stopped-killed-), and still not working. So any solution?

**Edit : Huawei Nova i7 no longer supportted by google service, so firebase messaging doesn't work**